# SpreadsheetDocument.loadDocument() excepción OdfValidationException

Tags: java, archivo, excepciones

Estoy intentando abrir un archivo usanndo ODFToolkit. Tengo el siguiente código:

*creo el archivo*

```
File libro = new File(filePath);
String hola = "hola";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(libro.getAbsolutePath());
fos.write(hola.getBytes());
```

*y trato de cargarlo*

```
ods = SpreadsheetDocument.loadDocument(libro);
```

y al intentar cargarlo me salta la excepción

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfValidationException; The ODF package 
'file:///C:/Users/x/eclipse-workspace/x/prueba.ods' shall be a ZIP file!
```

Estoy usando mal el metodo loadDocument()? Cómo puedo obtener el documento para crear tablas? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por mucho que le cambies el nombre, lo que creas con el primer código es un archivo de texto puro y duro. El ODFToolkit espera trabajar con documentos ODF...

Comment: @SJuan76 gracias. También he intendo hacerlo con `ods = SpreadsheetDocument.newSpreadsheetDocument();` 

pero me salta esta excepción **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/rootdev/javardfa/StatementSink** por eso recurrí a crearlo directamente de la otra forma. Alguna sugerencia por favor?

Comment: `ods = SpreadsheetDocument.newSpreadsheetDocument()` parece la forma correcta de hacerlo, lo que hay que hacer es solucionar ese error (que suena a que te has dejado alguna librería). Con lo que haces en la pregunta, lo único que consigues es que te salte otro error ANTES del `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: Revisa la documentación de la librería ODF para ver que jars necesita, y si sigue fallando busca en que jar está la clase que falta (Google); ya hay muchas preguntas sobre ese error aquí.

Comment: @SJuan76 muchas gracias. He encontrado el jar necesario. Pondré como respuesta el enlace.

Comment: Realmente, creo que como la solución no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta que planteaste y como ya hay otras preguntas sobre `NoClassDefFoundException`,  quizás sería mejor simplemente borrar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras las respuestas de @SJuan76 he creado el documento de esta manera `SpreadsheetDocument ods = SpreadsheetDocument.newSpreadsheetDocument();` añadiendo el jar del siguiente enlace https://incubator.apache.org/odftoolkit/simple/gettingstartguide.html